# RAD 8.5 - No Portlet Project option available

Tags: websphere-portal, ibm-rad

Just installed trial version of RAD 8.5 but I don't see any option to create a Portlet Project.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: On the new project wizard windpw is there any option to "Show all Wizards" or something like that?

Comment: @NickRoth: Nothing that I came across. I had to go back to Installation Installation Manager, select Modify and then select some more development tools. Those development tools were not selected by default when I installed RAD 8.5 for the first time. After having those extra development tools installed, it is showing Portlet Project now. Thanks for the reply :).

Answer (score 5):

You can also add the capabilities if they're not there by going to windows/preferences/capabilities. Click Advanced. Expand Web Develkoper(advanced) and enable Portal Development